# How to capture photos with cv2.imwrite()?

Tags: python, opencv

`cv2.imwrite()` is not working. I am trying for taking 100 photos when face will be detected.

Here is the code given:

```py
import cv2
import datetime
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
while True:

    _,frame = cap.read()
    greyImg = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(greyImg,1.3,5)    
    for x,y,w,h in face:

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0),5)
        time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D-%m-%Y")
        file_name = f"{time_stamp}-face.jpg"
        for i in range(100):

            cv2.imwrite(file_name,greyImg)       
    cv2.imshow("Face recogniton", cv2.flip(frame,1))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):

        break
```

Comment: Why are you writing the same image with the same name to disk 100 times?

Comment: why are you not checking for any errors during `cap.read()`? why did you not check that opening the camera device actually worked? `assert cap.isOpened()` *once*, and `ret, frame = cap.read(); if not ret: break` in the loop -- this question is asked multiple times a day. you didn't debug your code. you should review [ask] and [mre]

Comment: what's that cvtColor doing there? it's wrong. VideoCapture returns BGR frames, and imwrite wants BGR frames. that cvtColor there _is an error_. -- and why is there no proper error description? your code may not even _try_ to imwrite anything, if it doesn't actually detect faces.

Comment: time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%D-%m-%Y")
for i in range(100):
    cv2.imwrite(f"{time_stamp}-face{i}.jpg", greyImg)

Answer (score 0):

The main bug in your code that you are looping the 100 times saving the same image.

This code is supposed to solve your issue:

```py
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
faces_counter: int = 0

while True:
    _,frame = cap.read()
    greyImg = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(greyImg,1.3,5)    
    if np.any(face):
        faces_counter += 1
    
    if faces_counter > 100:
        break

    for x,y,w,h in face:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0),5)

        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H_%M_%S")

        file_name = f"Img_{current_time}_{faces_counter}-face.png"
        
                cv2.imwrite(f"{str(file_name)}", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Face recogniton", cv2.flip(frame,1))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
```